# Strikethrough a \cref-generated cross-reference

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, strikeout

I'm looking to strikethrough a cross-reference generated with `\cref`.  I thought a basic example like the following would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

Consider
\begin{equation}\label{eq:int}
\int_a^bf(t)dt=0    
\end{equation}

Then \st{Ignore \cref{eq:int}.}

\end{document}
```

However, I get an error message about one-too-many `}` symbols.  To clarify, I would like the cross-reference to still be present (and blue, but I don't think that's important to this example), but have the strikethrough on top of it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Similar problems have already showed up; the simplest workaround is `\st{Ignore \mbox{\cref{eq:int}}.}`

Answer (score 2):

This is a by-pass solution with `TikZ`, striking out the text by overprinting with a line, using a node aligned to the baseline and applying the `west` and `east` node anchors as drawing start and end points.

Using `TikZ` styles and/or `pgfkeys` etc. the customization would even better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\tikzst}[2][line width=1pt,blue,opacity=0.4]{%
  \tikz[baseline]{ \node[anchor=text,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] (A) {#2}; \draw[#1] ([xshift=-0.1ex]A.west) --  ([xshift=0.1ex]A.east);}%
}

\begin{document}

Consider
\begin{equation}\label{eq:int}
\int_a^bf(t)dt=0    
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  c^2 = a^{2} + b^{2} \label{eq:pythagoras}
\end{equation}

Then \tikzst{Ignore \cref{eq:int}}, but think of \tikzst[red]{\cref{eq:pythagoras}}!

\end{document}
```

[image]